# Non-positive width or height in function cvCreateMatHeader in opencv

Tags: c, image-processing, ubuntu, opencv

This is my code where I am trying to write to a file.filtergaborodd and filtergaboreven both are IplImage* objects and I am writing their contents to a text file.

```
for(int i=0;i<filtergaborodd->height;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<filtergaborodd->width;j++)
           {

               fprintf(fidf,"%.5f\t",(float)((filtergaborodd->imageData)[i*filtergaborodd->widthStep+j]));
               fprintf(fidf,"%.5f\t",(float)((filtergaboreven->imageData)[i*filtergaboreven->widthStep+j]));

               cout<<i<<j<<endl;
           }
        }
```

But when I try to run this I get the following error:  Non-positive width or height in function cvCreateMatHeader in opencv.

I am not able to understand the reason for this error.Can someone help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message showed that your problem was not in the code you gave.

error: Non-positive width or height in function cvCreateMatHeader means that you give a wrong number when you are constructing the Iplimage or Mat.

Maybe you can check those part of code:)

Comment: hEY doNG,I fixed the problem.It was actually the way I was trying to access the data that was mesing it up.